# How to implement focus/blur response in a custom react-native TextInput

Tags: react-native, textfield

I implemented a *custom* react-native TextInput backed by a native library. It's working pretty well except that when I tap outside of the textfield, it doesn't blur automatically and the keyboard doesn't disappear. I also tried with `Keyboard.dismiss()`, it doesn't work either. I looked at the 'official' `TextInput` implementation to replicate it without any success.

I added this code in my custom implementation (`componentDidMount`)

```
    if (this.context.focusEmitter) {
      this._focusSubscription = this.context.focusEmitter.addListener(
        'focus',
        el => {
          if (this === el) {
            this.requestAnimationFrame(this.focus);
          } else if (this.isFocused()) {
            this.blur();
          }
        },
      );
      if (this.props.autoFocus) {
        this.context.onFocusRequested(this);
      }
    } else {
      if (this.props.autoFocus) {
        this.requestAnimationFrame(this.focus);
      }
    }
```

and I also defined the required contextTypes

```
    static contextTypes = {
      focusEmitter: PropTypes.instanceOf(EventEmitter)
    }
```

[code from TextInput](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8b5e3fc16b1e58441318b6ada629dcff572dd120/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L818)

The problem I have is that the `focusEmitter` is undefined in the context and I have no idea from where it's provided in the context nor if it's actually the way it works for the regular `TextInput`. The only occurence of `focusEmitter` I could find in the react-native repo is in NavigatorIOS which I don't even use in my app.
Could anyone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to do what you want is to use `Keyboard.dismiss()` on a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` just like following example:

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';
...
render(){
  return(
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <View>
        // Return everything here
        <TextInput />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

So when you tap outside the input it will dismiss keyboard and blur the `TextInput`.

Comment: What you suggest would work on a regular TextInput and actually wouldn’t be required since it works that way out of the box. I already tried it anyway and it doesn’t work with my custom component. I suspect Keyboard.dismiss is using the same internal mechanism, possibly through that focusEmitter but I don’t know for sure.